# jquery xml selector not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer

i'm outputing an xml element in a php page:

```
<div id="week">
<week>
    <weekBegin>20131118</weekBegin>
    <Monday>
        <appointment>
            <beginTime>12:30</beginTime>
            <endTime>12:50</endTime>
            <studentName>1张三</studentName>
            <studentID>220102232</studentID>
            <mobile>15062271065</mobile>
            <writingTitle>Which is more important, ideas or funding?</writingTitle>
            <writingType>四六级</writingType>
            <writingPrinted>N</writingPrinted>
            <writingEmailed>N</writingEmailed>
        </appointment>
    </Monday>
</week>
</div>
```

I try to use jquery '$("#week monday")' to select the monday element, and it works in chrome and IE 10. but it failed in IE 8, IE8 selects nothing.

I wanted the server php page to return this  xml element in a 'div', which i could manipulate via jquery. seems can't get this.

I thought jQuery is cross-browser, but it's not?

Is there a way that I can achieve this still using jQuery?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like a problem with custom element tagnames, in your header add `document.createElement('week');document.createElement('weekBegin');document.createElement('Monday');document.createElement('appointment');..` and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 and below deos not support custom tag names, you you want to add them then you need to use a hack.

If you want to support those custom tags, then you need to call `document.createElement(tagName)` before the element is added to the dom. See the [AngularJS IE compatibility Doc Point 4](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

Try adding the below to your page header

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
  <script>
    document.createElement('week');
    document.createElement('weekBegin');
    document.createElement('Monday');
    document.createElement('appointment');
    document.createElement('beginTime');
    document.createElement('endTime');
    .....
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hi @Arun P Johny! Can I ask another question? as I got the elements in one <week>, is there a way to programatically document.createElement every tagname? Thank you!!

Comment: @LukeChen I don't think so, but you can use an array to keep it short... or you can parse the xml as a string then then iterate through it to create the elements I think